# Open CV - Matching video frame with image

Tags: c++, opencv, openframeworks

I am trying to compare the key points of a video frame with an image I upload. This is my code. The img parameter is the uploaded picture, pixels_color is the pixels from the frame, height and width is also from the frame.

```
int Image::match(ofImage img){

    cv::SurfFeatureDetector detector(400);
    vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2;
    cv::Mat img1(height, width, CV_8UC3, pixels_color);
    cv::Mat img2(img.getHeight(), img.getWidth(), CV_8UC3, img.getPixels());

    detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
    detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);

    cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
    cv::Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;
    extractor.compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);
    extractor.compute(img2, keypoints2, descriptors2);

    cv::BruteForceMatcher<cv::L2<float>> matcher;
    vector<cv::DMatch> matches;
    matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);

    return matches.size();
}
```

The problem is the return is always size of keypoints1 . I do not know why, unless my keypoints2 has size 0, the return will always be the size of keypoints1.

It does not matter if the `ofImage img` has something to do with the frame or not, it will always return the size of keypoints1. Here is an example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still didn't understand what happened, so I used a different approach, I used FlannBasedMatcher with a normalization, with permitted me to achieve what I wanted to:

```
int Image::match(ofImage img){

    bool result = false;
    float neares_neighbor_distance_ratio = 0.7f;

    cv::SurfFeatureDetector detector(400);
    vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2;
    cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
    cv::Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;

    cv::Mat img1(height, width, CV_8UC3, pixels_color);
    cv::Mat img2(img.getHeight(), img.getWidth(), CV_8UC3, img.getPixels());

    detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
    detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);

    extractor.compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);
    extractor.compute(img2, keypoints2, descriptors2);

    cv::FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
    vector<vector<cv::DMatch>> matches; 
    matcher.knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches, 2);

    vector<cv::DMatch> good_matches;
    good_matches.reserve(matches.size());  

    for(size_t i = 0; i < matches.size(); ++i)
    { 
        if(matches[i].size() < 2)
            continue;

        const cv::DMatch &m1 = matches[i][0];
        const cv::DMatch &m2 = matches[i][1];

        if(m1.distance <= neares_neighbor_distance_ratio * m2.distance)        
            good_matches.push_back(m1);     
    }

    return good_matches.size();
}
```

the method is a bit bigger, but it worked I guess.